# How can I use fxml in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml

I was wondering about using fxml in eclipse.
I watched a Video about JavaFX where the Creator handles the UI with a fxml File(He uses Eclipse too).
But my Eclipse doesnt recognize that I use fxml(Maybe doesnt have fxml?).
Is there any way I can add fxml to eclipse?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/579QB.png)

Comment: Look at [e(fx)clipse](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can also get the e(fx)clipse plugin (which allows you to create fxmls) by opening Eclipse, clicking Help, scrolling down to the Eclipse Marketplace, and searching e(fx)clipse. Install, and then just restart Eclipse. To create a new JavaFX project, go to File->New->Project...->JavaFX->JavaFX Project, and you should be good to go (these instructions are based on using Eclipse Neon).